# Pymongo data saved by app is not available in mongo shell

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo, persistence

I'm building a flask app using pymongo. Within my python script the data saves with .save() just like it should, and can be retrieved with .find() as it should, and it also persists if I restart the app. However, if I check the mongo database from another terminal, or from the same terminal after stopping the app, the data isn't there. To make sure I'm using pymongo correctly I copy and pasted this basic script below from w3schools.com:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["mydatabase"]
mycol = mydb["customers"]
mydict = { "name": "John", "address": "Highway 37" }
obj = mycol.insert_one(mydict)
obj = mycol.find_one()
print(obj)
```

The output is:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5f09b0c4dfedb570e2f5411e'), 'name': 'John', 'address': 'Highway 37'}
```

just as you'd expect. This is the result of show databases before running the above script:

```
> show databases
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
```

and this is the result of running show databases after running the script:

```
> show databases
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
mydatabase  0.000GB
```

**HOWEVER**:

```
use mydatabase
db.mydatabase.customers.find()
>
```

Either the collections have not persisted in the mongo server I am tryin to connect to, or they're just not showing in the shell for some reason. Here's my /etc/mongod.config file:
(commented lines removed so stackoverflow doesn't format it as markup)

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
   enabled: true


systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1

processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo
```

and I'm not sure if these are relevant but there have always been startup warnings when I enter the mongo shell:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.8
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("20a57a18-201c-4393-a9a3-c0ee53e028e8") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.8
Server has startup warnings: 
2020-07-11T12:16:02.034+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2020-07-11T12:16:02.034+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2020-07-11T12:16:02.034+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2020-07-11T12:16:02.940+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2020-07-11T12:16:02.940+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2020-07-11T12:16:02.940+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2020-07-11T12:16:02.940+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

upon seeing "connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb" I attempted to alter the MongoClient connection to "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb" just to see if that would work, but it just throws and error:

```
    /home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/compression_support.py:55: UserWarning: Unsupported compressor: disabled
  warnings.warn("Unsupported compressor: %s" % (compressor,))
/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/common.py:756: UserWarning: Unknown option gssapiservicename
  warnings.warn(str(exc))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [syntax](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db-collection-find) you want is:

```
db.customers.find()
```

at the shell. You have already specified the database with the `use` command.

To list the collections, it's:

```
show collections
```

Comment: This was my issue, thank you!! No more pulling my hair out! :)

Comment: Sorry about that! New to the platform.